# cannot use function (type func()) as type in argument

Tags: go, interface

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strings"

    "asl.com/asl"
)

/*
Trivial service to demonstrate chaining service together
Message starts in originator, travels through a couple formatters, and then gets back to originator
*/

type MessageTest struct {
    Body string `json:"body"`
}
var s *asl.Service
func main() {
    var (
        err error
        cid string
    )
    //var m MessageDelivery
       var g asl.MessageHandler
       g = UpperCaseHandler

    //  UpperCaser := asl.NewService("UpperCaser", "", false)
    UpperCaser := asl.NewService("UpperCaser")
    if err = UpperCaser.ConsumeFunc("asl-service-uc", []string{"asl-service-uc"},func() interface{} {
        return ""
    },g); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting consumer: %v", err)
    }
    //  Repeater := asl.NewService("Repeater", "", false)
    Repeater := asl.NewService("Repeater")
    if err = Repeater.ConsumeFunc("asl-service-repeat", []string{"asl-service-repeat"}, func() interface{} {
        return ""
    }, RepeatHandler); err != nil {
        //if err = Repeater.ConsumeFunc("asl-service-repeat", []string{"asl-service-repeat"}, mg asl.MessageGenerator, mh asl.MessageHandler); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error starting consumer: %v", err)
    }

    //  originator := asl.NewService("Originator", "", false)
    originator := asl.NewService("Originator")

    deliveryChan := make(chan asl.MessageDelivery)
    m := asl.MessagePublishing{
        Message:     MessageTest{"this is a test"},
        RoutingKeys: []string{"asl-service-uc", "asl-service-repeat"},
    }
    if cid, err = originator.RPCPublish(m, deliveryChan); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to publish: %v", err)
    }

    message := <-deliveryChan
    log.Printf("Originator Got: %+v", message.Message)
    originator.RemoveQueue(cid)
    UpperCaser.Wait()
}

func UpperCaseHandler(md asl.MessageDelivery) {
     s.Reply(MessageTest{strings.ToUpper(md.Message.(string))}, md.Delivery)
}

func RepeatHandler(md asl.MessageDelivery) {
     s.Reply(MessageTest{strings.Repeat(md.Message.(string), 5)}, md.Delivery)
}


package asl
```

> ```
> Error
> ```
>
> ./chains.go:26:10: cannot use UpperCaseHandler      (typefunc(asl.MessageDelivery)) as type asl.MessageHandler in
>   assignment
>   ./chains.go:37:86: cannot use RepeatHandler (type func(asl.MessageDelivery)) as type asl.MessageHandler in
>   argument to Repeater.ConsumeFunc

```
type MessageDelivery struct {
    Delivery amqp.Delivery
    Message  interface{}
    Error    error
    Context  *Context
}    
type MessageGenerator func() interface{}

type MessageHandler func(MessageDelivery) (interface{}, error)
```

I tried running the code,where am i going wrong,how do i right pass function as argument to another function. The function returns
interface and error. Though function is taking MessageDelivery Struct as argument,function signature is same.where am i going wrong

Comment: I can't find that busboy library, is it public? It looks like your functions don't have the right signature, can you include the type definition of busboy.MessageHandler

Comment: type MessageHandler func(MessageDelivery) (interface{}, error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the function as an argument correctly but they do not match the expected signature.  Change your functions to:

```
func UpperCaseHandler(md busboy.MessageDelivery) (interface{}, error} {
     s.Reply(MessageTest{strings.ToUpper(md.Message.(string))}, md.Delivery)
     return nil, nil
}

func RepeatHandler(md busboy.MessageDelivery) (interface{}, error} {
     s.Reply(MessageTest{strings.Repeat(md.Message.(string), 5)}, md.Delivery)
     return nil, nil
}
```

Comment: `too many arguments to return have (nil, nil) want ()` suggests that you have added the `return nil, nil` but not updated the function signature to include `(interface{}, error}` (which would also explain why you still can't use it as a MessageHandler).  This worked in a simpler example: https://play.golang.org/p/fP1dQa-cfmC

Comment: That was just an example without the required dependencies to show the principles work, not something to include in your code. What is the function signature for your functions now? Have you added the `(interface {}, error)` part?