# Duck typing go functions

Tags: go, compiler-errors

When I try to use an interface instead of the real struct as a return value of a function, the compiler errors. Shouldn't this be possible with duck typing?

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
)

type Runner interface {
    Run() error
}

type My struct {
    Cmd func(name string, arg ...string) Runner
}

func main() {
    compiles := My{
        Cmd: func(name string, arg ...string) Runner {
            return exec.Command(name, arg...)
        },
    }
    doesNotCompile := My{
        Cmd: exec.Command,
    }
}
```

> ./prog.go:22:3: cannot use exec.Command (type func(string, ...string) *exec.Cmd) as type func(string, ...string) Runner in field value

https://play.golang.org/p/gfwMgiC6WLP

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50207643/13860

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54744850/13860

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're looking for here is variance in the type system. Some type systems and types support covariance and contravariance, but Go's interfaces do not.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54751503/1406669